# Doctrine ResultSetMapping(Builder) is not showing any results

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, sqlresultsetmapping

My normal query was looking like this.

```
$qb = $placeRepository->createQueryBuilder('p');
var_dump($qb->getQuery()->getResult());
```

I'll get few results as objects.
So this is the normal behaviour.

Then I want to add a custom field with `ResultSetMapping`.

```
$qb = $placeRepository->createQueryBuilder('p');
$qb->addSelect('123 as distance');

$rsm = new ResultSetMapping;
$rsm->addEntityResult(Place::class, 'p');
$rsm->addFieldResult('p', 'id', 'id');
$rsm->addScalarResult('distance', 'distance');

var_dump($qb->getQuery()->setResultSetMapping($rsm)->getResult());
```

With a `ResultSetMappingBuilder` its also not working.

```
$qb = $placeRepository->createQueryBuilder('p');
$qb->addSelect('123 as distance');

$rsm = $placeRepository->createResultSetMappingBuilder('p');

var_dump($qb->getQuery()->setResultSetMapping($rsm)->getResult());
```

**Not working means:** Array with zero items in it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok found it.
But not working like I want

```
/** @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em */
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

// Working but bad because defining all by yourself
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
$rsm->addEntityResult(Place::class, 'p');
$rsm->addFieldResult('p','p_id','id');

// Good
$rsmB = new ResultSetMappingBuilder($em);
$rsmB->addRootEntityFromClassMetadata(Place::class, 'p');
// Not working because separate field
//$rsmB->addScalarResult('distance', 'distance');
// Not working because not found ... (not a @ORM\Column)
$rsmB->addFieldResult('p', 'distance', 'distance');
```

I added comments why its not working.

Now I'm going to loop

Comment: try  this `var_dump($qb->getQuery()->select($rsmB->generateSelectClause())->setResultSetMapping($rsm)->getResult());`